# Prove that if $M$ is any λ-NFA with $λ ∉ L(M)$, we can construct a new ordinary NFA $O$, such that $L(O) = L(M)^R$

Tags: automata, formal-languages, finite-automata

Hint: Prove that if $M$ is any $\lambda$-NFA with $\lambda \not\in L(M)$, there exists an ordinary NFA $N$, with exactly one final state, such that $L(M) = L(N)$ to prove the above statement.

Comment: Is $L(M)^R$ denote the reversal of $L(M)$?  Have you studied the basic closure properties of regular languages?

Comment: Yes, it denotes reversal. Also, I do not understand how do we go about proving it using closure.

Comment: Closure under reversal is one of the basic closure properties of regular languages.  If you were allowed to use that fact, the proof would be one short line.  Much more likely that they want you to prove that fact.  Think what happens to an NFA if you reverse the direction of all transitions.